# Why is conversion from LocalDateTime to Instant not working?

Tags: java, java-time, localdatetime, java.time.instant

Do you know why 4. and 6. prints have wrong hours in following code?

```java
LocalDateTime ldtNow = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime ldtNextMonth = ldtNow.plusMonths(1);

System.out.println("1. " + ldtNow);
System.out.println("2. " + ldtNextMonth);

System.out.println("3. " + ldtNow.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toString());
System.out.println("4. " + ldtNextMonth.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toString());

System.out.println("5. " + ldtNow.atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault()).toInstant().toString());
System.out.println("6. " + ldtNextMonth.atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault()).toInstant().toString());
```

This is what it prints:

```
 1. 2022-10-26T16:53:59.691891
 2. 2022-11-26T16:53:59.691891

 3. 2022-10-26T14:53:59.691891Z
 4. 2022-11-26T15:53:59.691891Z //WRONG?

 5. 2022-10-26T14:53:59.691891Z
 6. 2022-11-26T15:53:59.691891Z //WRONG?
```

Prints 3. & 4. test it with ZoneId and prints 5. & 6. with ZoneOffset.

The only difference between 3. & 4. (and 5. & 6.) is the usage of  *LocalDateTime#plusMonths* method. What should I do to get right result for zero time (*2022-11-26T**14**:53:59.691891Z*)?

Comment: You seem to have involved a DST change by accident. What's the default time zone of your system? It may change at the end of october and add an hour! Take `ZoneId.of("UTC")` instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`…

Comment: wouldn't the 2nd one also be an hour plus 16 if they add an hour after October @deHaar

Comment: That's what OP has to find out… I'm not sure it's the case, but it's possible… That means try and see.

Comment: My system default is _Europe/Prague_. I didn't think of that it could be time change at the end of October. You are right! When using `ZoneId.of("UTC")` it gives equal results.

Comment: @devin NO, `LocalDateTime` has no concept of time zone (also the reason to need  `atZone()` to convert it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `atZone()` returns ZonedDatetime and then you experience the daylight saving effect.
Different zones around the globe have daylight saving at different dates.

So your prints are:

```bash
 1. 2022-10-26T16:53:59.691891  // LocalDateTime
 2. 2022-11-26T16:53:59.691891  // LocalDateTime

 3. 2022-10-26T14:53:59.691891Z // ZonedDateTime
 4. 2022-11-26T15:53:59.691891Z // ZonedDateTime

 5. 2022-10-26T14:53:59.691891Z // ZonedDateTime
 6. 2022-11-26T15:53:59.691891Z // ZonedDateTime
```

`UTC` time zone is like a reference point for any other timezone. For example `CET, central european time` timezone have the zone offsets of `UTC+2` and `UTC+1` depending on the period of the year.

You can see this effect by executing the following snippet:

```java
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ldtNow.atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ldtNextMonth.atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault());

System.out.println(ZoneOffset.from(zdt1));   // prints +02:00
System.out.println(ZoneOffset.from(zdt2));   // prints +01:00
```

Comment: More precisely, Central Europe TIme is used in several European and North African time zones *most*, not all, of which use summer time (DST). A few stay on UTC+1 all year. Otherwise a correct answer.